# Avatar image in Leverice

Tags: message, user-profile, avatar

Is there a way to change my avatar image in Leverice, and if so, can I have different profile pictures for different workspaces? Trying to modify it from the default avatar with initials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change it and you can customize which avatars appear in which Leverice workspaces. Just click on your avatar that appears on the immediate left of the message text box and it will launch a window where you can make these changes.